# BaseBean anti-pattern in Python

Tags: python, oop, anti-patterns

Background: Coming from Perl world, I'm currently learning Python in my new
job.  Apart from doing the work, I'm also trying to get more of "real OOP"
and "pythonic" thinking into my brain cell flow, mostly by reading SO, Python
docs and various articles.

Now in OO design section of [Anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) page, Wikipedia lists this
*BaseBean*, which on [its own page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BaseBean) is described as:

> In object-oriented programming, a BaseBean is a utility object from which
>   concrete entities are derived (via subclassing). Proper design suggests
>   that the inherited functionality should be provided via delegation instead.
>   The BaseBean is an example of an anti-pattern (where the "Bean" part of the
>   name comes from the standard Java naming convention for a generic entity
>   object, or JavaBean).

Maybe it's because I have no experience with Java, maybe it's for other reason,
but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this explanation.  However, I'm
feeling that few lines of code would be worth thousand words here.

Could anyone help clarify this for me?  Preferably using a simple example in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this quote in the Wikipedia article:

> Using inheritance causes the derived class to rely on the internals of
>   a base class which may be out of the control of the developer. While
>   the utility classes are typically stable and fairly similar across
>   implementations, some innocuous change in the future could break the
>   derived class (since the relationship is not well defined). In
>   addition, it muddies the business meaning of the derived class. For
>   example, an order is not a vector, although an order may contain a
>   vector of line items.

it seems to be referring to things like this:

```
class Order(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return """
Customer: {customer}
Address: {address}
        """.format(**self)

o = Order(customer = "Joe Customer", address = "123 Market St")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't find your example very clear--how does it illustrate the anti-pattern?.  And the Wikipedia article is unclear to me in the first place (e.g. what they mean by "utility classes"?; across what implementations?; what vector?).

Comment: What the Wikipedia example mentions is using a more general class (list or vector) *AS* your order class.  Consider an order class.  It should ideally have order metadata and a list of line items.  So the cited example in Wikipedia is using your "utility" (vector/list) class *AS* your order class.  It is not a "isa" relationship - it's a "hasa" relation ship.  Orders have a list of line items... they are not a list of line items themselves.